# Create an array full of -1;

Tags: c#, arrays

Instead of starting off every value at 0 like c# normally does, I am wondering if there is way to start at a specific number like -1 without having to loop through replacing every 0 with -1 after initialization?

Comment: Possibly, but the answers here were considerably more helpful, thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public static int[] Initialize( this int[] instance , int value )
{
  if ( instance == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance") ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < instance.Length ; ++i )
  {
    instance[i] = value ;
  }
  return instance ;
}
```

which would let you say something like

```
int[] foo = new int[2048].Initialize(-1) ;
```

You might get some performance increase by going unsafe and using pointers, since you won't incur the overhead of array bounds checking, something like this:

```
public static unsafe int[] Initialize( this int[] instance , int value )
{
  if ( instance == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance") ;
  fixed ( int *addr = instance )
  {
    int *p    = addr ;
    int *pMax = addr+instance.Length ;
    while ( p < pMax )
    {
      *(p++) = value ;
    }
    return instance ;
  }
```

If you'll only ever want to set the array to -1, you can make it even faster by using `memset()`, since we know that all the bytes will be 0xFF. So...

```
    public static unsafe int[] InitializeToMinus1( this int[] instance )
    {
        if ( instance == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
        fixed( void *p = instance )
        {
            IntPtr    addr  = new IntPtr(p) ;
            const int hexFF = 0x000000FF ;
            int       bytes = instance.Length * sizeof(int) ;
            memset( addr , hexFF , bytes ) ;
        }
        return instance ;
    }

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint="memset", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern IntPtr memset( IntPtr addr , int c , int count ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! It looks like I am going to have to create something custom like this. Thanks for all the examples they were really helpful, hadent even thought of using something nonstandard to do it.

Answer (score 5):

using something like this

```
 var myArray =  Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 1000000).ToArray();
```

[important note; it is slower than looping manually](http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-array)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it's suboptimal.

Comment: Yes, it's slower mostly because `ToArray` does not know final number of elements and array is being reallocated from time to time to get more space for new elements.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, i like to use ilspy to see what happen under the hood, i didn't for this case but good to know :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, possible.

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 10).ToArray();  
    Console.WriteLine (arr);
}
```

Not entirely sure what happens behind the scenes so it will probably still loop over the values in your list. That will be hard to avoid though.

Different solution:

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new List<int>(new int[10]).Select(x => x = -1).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine (arr);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will loop over under the hoods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Repeat`:

```
int[] array = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 5).ToArray();
```

As mentioned elsewhere, this is syntactic sugar - a loop will still be run, and you'll incur the overhead of converting the `IEnumerable` produced back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int[] intArray =  Enumerable.Repeat(-1, [Length]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Enumerable* class may help, like below :

```
IEnumerable<int> array = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 15);  // or whatever range you'd like
```

Comment: But than it's not really an array ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Code...

```
items =  items.Select(s => s = -1).ToArray();
```

Good Luck!